# app inventor emulator issue

Tags: android, app-inventor

hi guys so I've been developing an app in app inventor. I have installed everything I need to make the whole block editor and emulator working as well, it was the 80+mb installer needed for app inventor extras that I am referring to.

Now I have a problem, when I open my project in app inventor and I open my phone emulator in the blocks editor at the same time, I do not understand why I cannot see my application from the phone's emulator menu... Any idea how to fix this guys? Any help would be much appreciated.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use "open the blocks editor" button every time and not previously downloaded .jnlp files.
When you open emulator in blocks editor using 'new emulator' button, wait for the phone screen to display the lock screen. Once you unlock the lock screen by swiping it, it will display home screen. Wait for the widgets to load. After they load, click on 'connect to device'. If you 'connect to device' >> 'emulator 5554' before the home screen loads, it doesn't work.
Take care of these points and you'll have no difficulties with emulator.